# Holomorphic function real at positive numbers is real at negative numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}- \{0\}$ and maps positive real numbers to real numbers.  I wish to show that $f(z)$ takes negative real numbers to real numbers as well.

Schwarz reflection tells us that $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ for $z$ in the right half plane.  If we could verify this also holds when $z$ is in the left half plane, we'd be done.  I could not get past this...

Comment: Does it help to consider the function $g(z) = f(-z)$?

Comment: Doesn't it suffice to consider $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar{z})} - f(z)$, which is holomorphic with zeroes on a set with an accumulation

Comment: When you say $g$ is holomorphic, on which domain do you mean?

Comment: the whole domain: $\mathbb{C} -\{0\}$.

Comment: Ok, I can solve the problem from here.  But how do we know $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic?

Comment: it follows from the more general fact that the composition of a holomorphic map with an anti-holomorphic map is anti-holomorphic, and the composition of two anti-holomorphic maps is holomorphic. This, by the way, is basically the same as saying "the composition of a reflection and a rotation is a reflection, and the composition of two reflections is a rotation"

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this fact.

Comment: Rather than making any general remarks about composing holomorphic and anti-holomorphic maps, just look at power series: if $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} c_n(z-a)^n$ on an open disc around $a$, then $\overline{f(\overline{z})} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \overline{c_n}(z-a)^n$ on that same disc. So $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ has a power series expansion around every point in the domain of $f(z)$, with complex-conjugate coefficients to those of $f(z)$. So $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, I just reviewed that argument in Stein's book.  One more question: how do you know that conjugating the coefficients in the power series does not cause it to diverge?

Comment: Oh...it's just the root test, correct?  The moduli of the new coefficients are unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$, this is holomorphic and defined on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Further, we know that $\overline{f(\bar z)} = f(z)$ for every positive real, which certainly is a set with accumulation points. So the two functions are identical.  Thus we have that for *any* real $z$, $\overline{f(z)} = f(z)$, and thus $f(z)$ is real.